# std::deque<std::string> count size in memory efficiently

Tags: c++, stl

I've been working on a basic log file class which truncates by 20% once it reaches as set size limit (e.g. 10Mb), I decided to store the file into a stringstream buffer and then store it log by log into a std::deque (used a std::deque instead of std::vector so I could easily pop from the top of the structure and not have to sort etc) the loading and storing is shown below:

```
    std::deque<std::string> vLogs;
    std::stringstream ssBuffer;
    std::string sLog;

    ssBuffer << in.rdbuf();
    in.close();

    while(getline(ssBuffer,sLog))
        vLogs.push_back(sLog);
```

the log file is designed so it truncates when it reaches a set size (e.g. 10Mb) so what I really want to do is check how large the std::string's are within vLogs - which I can do in the following way:

```
    int nSize = 0;
    for(auto it = vLogs.begin(); it != vLogs.end(); ++it)
        nSize += it->size();

    do{
        nSize -= vLogs.front().size();
        vLogs.pop_front();
    }while(nSize > (MAX_SIZE * 0.8));
```

The question I'm asking is whether there is a more efficient way on getting the actual size taken up by the std::strings instead of doing it manually like I am now.

thanks - any more information just ask.

Comment: Do your own class that will have a `std::deque` and a **memory size counter** and monitor insertions (e.g., add size of memory inserted to the counter) and extractions (e.g., subtract size of memory extracted from the counter).

Comment: Could you not have your deque be a member of a logging class and update the total size every time you push and pop, that way you always keep the size up to date and if the new item log size added to the total exceeds the threshold then you pop until the total is less than the threshold

Comment: Yeah, I think you both nailed this on the head - I ignored this because of my over simplified approach - create an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your own class that will have a `std::deque` and a **memory size counter** and monitor insertions (e.g., add size of memory inserted to the counter) and extractions (e.g., subtract size of memory extracted from the counter).

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're adding up the sizes many many times.  This isn't necessary.

You can either

- add up all the sizes, then adjust the total down each time you remove an item

or

- add up the sizes in reverse starting from the tail, and once you reach the threshold, remove all items from that point to the beginning

Comment: I remove an item each time I go through the while loop already - although I like your second idea, find 20% of total and remove from top until that 20% has been removed.

Comment: @Mike: Do you understand the difference between "adjust the total down when you remove an item" vs "recalculate the total from scratch when you remove an item" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I rushed this example - that is what i'm currently doing.